Time-average convergence of $ \lim_{T\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{T}\int_{0}^{T}e^{-it\mathbf{\hat{H}}}\boldsymbol{\hat{\rho}}e^{it\mathbf{\hat{H}}}$
The setting: Let $\mathscr{H}$ be an arbitrary Hilbert space, and let $\mathbf{\hat{H}}$ be a self-adjoint operator acting in said Hilbert space. Let $\boldsymbol{\hat{\rho}}$ be a positive definite trace-class operator with trace 1.
(QUESTION )
I am interested in the convergence of the following long-time average limit. I am wondering if it always converges or not. By convergence here we mean convergence in with respect to the trace norm topology $\|\mathbf{\hat{A}}\|_{1}:=Tr\{|\mathbf{\hat{A}}|\}$.
$$
\lim_{T\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{T}\int_{0}^{T}e^{-it\mathbf{\hat{H}}}\boldsymbol{\hat{\rho}}e^{it\mathbf{\hat{H}}}
$$
(My THOUGHTS AND RELATED WORK)
My initial thoughts are that the convergence will depend on the spectrum of the operator $\mathbf{\hat{H}}$. E.g. in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.07538 page 11 (equation 23) If $\mathscr{H}$ is finite-dimensional and $\mathbf{\hat{H}}$ is non-degenerate and full-rank, then
$$
\lim_{T\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{T}\int_{0}^{T}e^{-it\mathbf{\hat{H}}}\boldsymbol{\hat{\rho}}e^{it\mathbf{\hat{H}}} = \sum_{n=1}^{dim(\mathscr{H})}\mathbf{\hat{P}}_{n}\boldsymbol{\hat{\rho}}\mathbf{\hat{P}}_{n}
$$
where $\mathbf{\hat{P}}_{n}$ are the projectors onto the different eigensubspaces of $\mathbf{\hat{H}}$, i.e. $\mathbf{\hat{H}} = \sum_{n=1}^{dim(\mathscr{H})}\lambda_{n}\mathbf{\hat{P}}_{n}$ where $\lambda_{n}$ are the eigenvalues.
Furthermore, in the infinite-dimensional case, things get messy and there is no longer convergence in the trace norm sense. In infinite dimensions $\mathbf{\hat{H}}$ could now be unbounded and have a purely continuous spectrum for example. Such a scenario leads to an operator that is not trace class. As an example consider the case where $\mathbf{\hat{H}}$ is a position operator $\mathbf{\hat{X}}$; i.e. for all $\psi\in\mathscr{H}$ one has $\mathbf{\hat{X}}\psi(x)=x\psi(x)$. I present my work below but the reader should be warned that I will be using notation from physics. Keep in mind that what I write below is not intended to be rigorous.
First note that $\boldsymbol{\hat{rho}}$ has a Hilbert-Schmidt kernel $K(x,y)$ and we may write
$$
\boldsymbol{\rho} = \int\int K(x,y)|x\rangle\langle y| dxdy
$$
now
\begin{equation}
\lim_{T\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{T}\int_{0}^{T}e^{-it\mathbf{\hat{X}}}\boldsymbol{\hat{\rho}}e^{it\mathbf{\hat{X}}} = \lim_{T\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{T}\int_{0}^{T}e^{-it\mathbf{\hat{X}}}\Bigg(\int\int K(x,y)|x\rangle\langle y| dxdy\Bigg)e^{it\mathbf{\hat{X}}} = 
\end{equation}
$$
(1) \lim_{T\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{T}\int_{0}^{T}\int\int K(x,y)e^{-it(x-y)}|x\rangle\langle y| dxdy =\int\int K(x,y) \big(\lim_{T\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{T}\int_{0}^{T}e^{-it(x-y)}\big)|x\rangle\langle y| dxdy   =
$$
$$
\int\int K(x,y) \delta(x-y)|x\rangle\langle y| dxdy  = \int K(x,x)|x\rangle\langle x|dx = K(\mathbf{\hat{X}},\mathbf{\hat{X}})
$$
The justificaion of swapping limits and integrals in the line marked (1) comes from dominated convergence theorem and Fubini-Tonelli theorem. As can be seen, as T goes to infinity, the object $\lim_{T\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{T}\int_{0}^{T}e^{-it\mathbf{\hat{X}}}\boldsymbol{\hat{\rho}}e^{it\mathbf{\hat{X}}}$ approaches a multiplication operator Leading me to believe that convergence w.r.t. operator norm may be had but not w.r.t. to trace norm. Hence, there is no convergence in the trace norm sense.
(MORE THOUGHTS/ SECONDARY QUESTION)
I am familiar with the von Neumann ergodic theory for Hilbert spaces. In our setting, for finite dimensions, it states that
$$
\lim_{T\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{T}\int_{0}^{T}e^{-it\mathbf{\hat{H}}} = \mathbf{\hat{P}}
$$
where the projector $\mathbf{\hat{P}}$ projects onto the kernel of $\big(\mathbf{I}-e^{-i\mathbf{\hat{H}}}\big)$. However, these theorems focus on the dynamics of vectors in Hilbert space while I am interested in the dynamics of the positive semidefinite trace-class operator of trace 1. I am not sure how to connect the two scenarios.
